# ubuntu 14.04 with windows 7 dual boot problem

Tags: 14.04, windows-7

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 using Live USB. I installed ubuntu in a totally empty partition with ext4 file system. Now when I restart the computer the loader takes me directly to windows 7 without giving me an option to choose ubuntu or windows. when I insert the USB drive and restart the computer a weird red screen appears when I boot from the USB with a term GRUB in a few lines. And it gives me option that i dont know anything about like load windows with SLIS or Load Windows without SLIS or something. When I go into windows the partition that i installed ubuntu in is totally vanished.I am able to use the `try ubuntu` option through which I have a access to Ubuntu O.S.

Please HELP me

Comment: And to mention I can go into ubuntu through usb boot option. I think its the new try ubuntu without installing option and I have tried reinstalling it too. Same results.

Comment: Thank you , but how do i do that :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should perform boot repair on your system using the access to Ubuntu from USB.

Run following commands in terminal as root

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)`

[this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) link will give you more methods and info on boot repair

[this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair/) is the official site for  boot-repair

Comment: Awsome. The ubuntu community boot repair page fixed the problem. fisrt link. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following commands to install boot-repair in Ubuntu 14-04 :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sh -c "sed -i 's/trusty/saucy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Bye